# Find the months in 2019 that had the highest and least number of new joinees respectively

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatable

Suppose I have an `employee` table with a column as `DateOfJoining`. And I have entered the data as

```
2019-12-4
2019-12-6
2019-12-5
2019-10-5
2010-08-17
```

Now I want write the SQL query to find the month in which there is maximum number of joinees.

Comment: what is stopping you to write the sql query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using aggregation and TOP

```
select top 1 month(dateofjoining),count(*) as totaljoining
from tablename
where year(dateofjoining)=2019
group by month(dateofjoining)
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: what if i want to find the month of maximum joiness in the year 2019.

Comment: I've edited - just to need a where condition @Pankaj4U

Answer (score 0):

Using `Derived table` and `row_number()`

Below query will give you the month in which there is maxmium number of joinees for each year.

```
select cnt,mnth,yr
from
(select count(DateOfJoining)cnt,
        month(DateOfJoining)mnth,
        year(DateOfJoining)yr,
        row_number()over(partition by year(DateOfJoining) order by count(DateOfJoining)desc)srno
 from #employee
 group by month(DateOfJoining),year(DateOfJoining) 
)tbl
where srno = 1
```

**output**

```
cnt         mnth        yr
----------- ----------- -----------
1           8           2010
3           12          2019
```

and if you want specifically for 2019 then add the condition `yr ='2019'` in the where clause.

```
where srno = 1
and yr =2019
```

**output**

```
cnt         mnth        yr
----------- ----------- -----------
3           12          2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You want both the biggest and least -- although I am guessing that you want at least one employee.

```
with e as (
      select year(dateofjoining) as yyyy,
             month(dateofjoining) as mm,
             count(*) as totaljoining
      from employee
      where dateofjoining >= '2019-01-01' and
            dateofjoining < '2020-01-01'
      group by year(dateofjoining), month(dateofjoining)
     )
select e.*
from ((select top (1) e.*
       from e
       order by totaljoining asc
      ) union all
      (select top (1) e.*
       from e
       order by totaljoining desc
      ) 
     ) e;
```

Notes:

- The date comparison uses direct comparisons to dates rather than using functions.  This is a best practice so the optimizer can use indexes.
- You want both the smallest and biggest value, so this uses a CTE so the `group by` is represented only once.
- This will not return months with no employees.
- If you want ties, then use `top (1) with ties`.